# "not resolved from current namespace" error, when calling C routines from R

Tags: c, r, namespaces, r-package, mgcv

I am recently doing some computational testing with `mgcv` GAM. Some original functions are modified, and some are added. In order not to break compatibility, for every function I want to modify, I create a new version with a `.zheyuan` surfix in function name. For example, with `Sl.fit` function for doing penalized least squares fitting, I will have an `Sl.fit.zheyuan`. I would simply collect all R functions I write into a standalone R script "zheyuan.R". By adding this file into the `R` directory of [`mgcv_1.8-17` package source](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/mgcv_1.8-17.tar.gz), and compiling this modified package into a local path, I could load it for testing purpose.

I have no problem in adding R routines, but not when adding C routines. No error occurs when installing the modified package, but when I call the R wrapper function of my added C routine, I would get the error as in my question title. If you are interested in my case, you may follow the following steps to reproduce such error.

**Step 1: download the latest package source**

Download the 1.8-17 version from the above link. Such link will die when new `mgcv` release is published on CRAN. But you can always go to [`mgcv` CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mgcv/index.html) to download the latest release.

Let's `untar` the source. First, remove the file `MD5`, so that we don't get annoying MD5 warning when compiling the modified version. In the following, we would add new stuff into `R` directory, and `src` directory.

**Step 2: create an R script**

Consider the following R wrapper function:

```
RX <- function (R, X) {
  X <- X + 0
  .Call("C_mgcv_RX", R, X)
  X
  }
```

Create an R script "zheyuan.R" to place this function, and add it into `mgcv/R`.

**Step 3: adding C routines**

C routines regarding matrix computations are normally under `src/mat.c`. So let's append a new function to the end of this script:

```
void mgcv_RX (SEXP R, SEXP X) {
  int nrowX = nrows(X);
  int ncolX = ncols(X);
  double one = 1.0;
  F77_CALL(dtrmm)("l", "u", "n", "n", &nrowX, &ncolX, &one, REAL(R), &nrowX, REAL(X), &nrowX);
  }
```

This is a simple routine multiplying an upper triangular matrix `R`, with a rectangular matrix `X`. The output matrix will overwrite `X`. Level-3 BLAS `dtrmm` will be called for this purpose. We don't need to worry about header files or runtime linking to BLAS library. Headers are availalbe in `mat.c`, and linking to BLAS is managed by R.

**Step 4: register C routine**

The above is insufficient. Each C routine in `mgcv` will appear in three places. For example, let's try searching a native C routine:

```
grep mgcv_RPPt mgcv/src/*
# mgcv/src/init.c:  {"mgcv_RPPt",(DL_FUNC)&mgcv_RPPt,3},
# mgcv/src/mat.c:void mgcv_RPPt(SEXP a,SEXP r, SEXP NT) {
# mgcv/src/mgcv.h:void mgcv_RPPt(SEXP a,SEXP r, SEXP NT);
```

We also need to append a header file `mgcv.h`, and register this C routine in `init.c`.

Let's append

```
void mgcv_RX (SEXP R, SEXP X);
```

to the end of `mgcv.h`, and inside `init.c`, do:

```
R_CallMethodDef CallMethods[] = {
  {"mgcv_pmmult2", (DL_FUNC) &mgcv_pmmult2,5},
  {"mgcv_Rpiqr", (DL_FUNC) &mgcv_Rpiqr,5}, 
  {"mgcv_tmm",(DL_FUNC)&mgcv_tmm,5}, 
  {"mgcv_Rpbsi",(DL_FUNC)&mgcv_Rpbsi,2},
  {"mgcv_RPPt",(DL_FUNC)&mgcv_RPPt,3},
  {"mgcv_Rpchol",(DL_FUNC)&mgcv_Rpchol,4},
  {"mgcv_Rpforwardsolve",(DL_FUNC)&mgcv_Rpforwardsolve,3},
  {"mgcv_Rpcross",(DL_FUNC)&mgcv_Rpcross,3},
  {"mgcv_RX",(DL_FUNC)&mgcv_RX,2},  //  we add this line
  {NULL, NULL, 0}
};
```

**Step 5: complie and load**

`tar` the modified `mgcv` folder to `mgcv.tar.gz`.

Open up a new, clean R session (possibly you need `R --vanilla` for start-up). Then specifying a local library path and run:

```
path <- getwd()  ## let's just use current working directory
## make sure you move "mgcv.tar.gz" into current working path
install.packages("mgcv.tar.gz", repos = NULL, lib = path)
library(mgcv, lib.loc = path)
```

**Step 6: test and get error**

```
R <- matrix(runif(25), 5)
R[lower.tri(R)] <- 0
X <- matrix(runif(25), 5)
mgcv:::RX(R, X)  ## function is not exported, so use `mgcv:::` to find it

# Error in .Call("C_mgcv_RX", R, X) : 
#   "C_mgcv_RX" not resolved from current namespace (mgcv)
```

Could anyone explain why and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a temporary "fix" now. Instead of

```
.Call("C_mgcv_RX", R, X)
```

use either of the following:

```
.Call(mgcv:::"C_mgcv_RX", R, X)
.Call(getNativeSymbolInfo("mgcv_RX"), R, X)
```

I came about this because I suddenly realize that C routines can be extracted by `:::`, too. Since package compilation is successful, there is no way that `mgcv:::` can not find this C routine. And yes, it works.

---

To check that our defined C routine is available in the shared library loaded, try

```
is.loaded("mgcv_RX")
# TRUE
```

To list all registered C routines in the loaded shared library, use

```
getDLLRegisteredRoutines("mgcv")
```

Comment: I understand it now. I should use `.Call(C_mgcv_RX, R, X)`, without quotation like `"C_mgcv_RX"`.